# How to give string in the url in RESTful api in Cakephp?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

As per the this Cakephp [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/REST.html#the-simple-setup) the simple setup for RESTful api :

```
HTTP Method     URL.method  Controller action invoked
GET     /recipes*.method*   RecipesController::index()
GET     /recipes/123.method     RecipesController::view(123)
POST    /recipes*.method*   RecipesController::add()
PUT     /recipes/123*.method*   RecipesController::edit(123)
DELETE  /recipes/123.method     RecipesController::delete(123)
POST    /recipes/123*.method*   RecipesController::edit(123)
```

here all the URL parameters are numeric i.e 123.
When I tried with the string i.e

```
GET     /recipes/test.json  RecipesController::view(123)
```

this gives me an error :

```
{
   code: "404"
   url: "/myproject/recipes/test.json"
   name: "Action RecipesController::test() could not be found."
}
```

here the URL

```
     "/myproject/recipes/test.json" // doesn't work

but 
      "/myproject/recipes/123.json" // works
```

I used the default `Router::mapResources('recipes')`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, reading [the API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/source-class-Router.html#462-510) for that piece of code, the value passed before the dot is matched automatically to an `id` or `UUID`. Right in that API there's the params definitions

> 'id' - The regular expression fragment to use when matching IDs. By
>   default, matches integer values and UUIDs.

What `mapResources` does is simply add a lot of `Router::connect` with some pre-established options (that basically has the form of **:controller/:action/:id**).

So, if the rule is to match ids (that cake considers to be ints) to a regular expression, clearly your string isn't passing that validation. So the `Router` skips that `connect` rule and goes to the other, until one matches. And the one that matches is in the form of **:controller/:action.extension** (probably). That's why you're getting that error, `test` is clearly not intended to be an action.

Luckily, one of that options that `mapResources`gives for customizing is the rule to match the `$id`.

To add the option of strings as "ids" (since that's the only variable the REST actions are going to receive if you add the connection routes with `mapResources`), change the regex that validates that rule like this

```
Router::mapResources('recipes', array('id'=>'[0-9A-Za-z]'));
```

or whatever rule you want to make (I'm bad with regex, so try to adjust it to what you need).

Take a look at [the docs](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-Router.html#_url) of the API to see what other options you can add.

Keep in mind that `mapResources` is there to make your life easier, so if you need more complicated routes with more params or something extra, consider forgetting about `mapResources` and constructing the routes yourself (like it says in the bottom of the page of the link you provided).

Comment: Did you tried changing the regex (as I said I'm bad with them). Try with `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` (I now realize I was allowing just one character... told you I was bad at it)

Comment: Great :) Keep in mind you'll have to adjust the regex if you want to allow spaces or hyphens or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Define in your routes below code :

```
// used for the rest API 
$routes->extensions(['json','xml']); // type of format you want to get response
$routes->resources('Api');
```

Then create a controller for the API like below inside controller folder

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\I18n\Time;
use Cake\Database\Type; 
Type::build('date')->setLocaleFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); // customize date format

// src/Controller/RecipesController.php
class ApiController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        // load Model 
        $this->loadModel('Sales'); // load model to fetch data from database
        $this->Auth->allow();      // allow URL to public in case of Auth check 
    }

    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');     
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

    }

    public function index($fromdate = null, $todate = null)
    {
        //set date range to fetch the sales in particular date 
        if(!empty($_GET['fromdate_utc']) && !empty($_GET['todate_utc'])){
            // if from amd to date are same add +1 day in to date to get result 
            $to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['todate_utc'] . ' +1 day'));
            $dateRage = array('Sales.SalesDate >= ' => $_GET['fromdate_utc'], 'Sales.SalesDate <=' => $to_date);
        }else{
            $dateRage = array();                    
        }

        $conditions = array(
            'and' => array($dateRage),
        );

        //$this->Auth->allow();
        $sales= $this->Sales->find('all', array(
                        'conditions' => $conditions
                    ))
                    ->select(['SalesNo', 'SalesDate', 'TotalValue', 'TotalDiscount', 'NetTotal', 'PaymentMode', 'Status'])
                    ->where(['StoreId' => '1']);
       // set data for view or response of API
        $this->set([
            'sales' => $sales,
            '_serialize' => ['sales']
        ]);
    }

}

?>
```

How to pass parameters in API URL for XML format check below :-

```
https://example.com/api/index.xml?fromdate_utc=2016-10-03&todate_utc=2016-10-03
```

How to pass parameters in API URL for JSON format check below :-

```
https://example.com/api/index.json?fromdate_utc=2016-10-03&todate_utc=2016-10-03
```