# Cake3 How to capture all characters in path property for rest routes

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

So, I have a piece of code, for my routes, like this:

```
Router::scope('/v1', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->resources( 'Files', [
        'map' => [
            'index' => ['action' => 'index', 'method' => 'GET', 'path' => ''],
            'create' => ['action' => 'add', 'method' => 'POST', 'path' => ''],
            'view' => ['action' => 'view', 'method' => 'GET', 'path' => ':id'],
            'update' => ['action' => 'edit', 'method' => ['PUT', 'PATCH'], 'path' => ':id'],
            'delete' => ['action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'path' => ':name'],
        ]
    ]);
});
```

And I have a URL like: http://192.168.1.197/v1/files/13625a1ddedcbc2011-40115501.jpg

And I want `13625a1ddedcbc2011-40115501.jpg` to be the `:name` parameter you see in the `'delete' => ['action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'path' => ':name']` route above, however, no matter what I do (I even tried regex here) I get the error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Controller\FilesController::delete(), 0 passed in

I have read the documentation on it maybe a thousand times: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html but I cannot figure out how.

I took a look at this answer, it is a bit vague on how to use it and it would mean I change ALL routes to be like this: [How to give string in the url in RESTful api in Cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108069/how-to-give-string-in-the-url-in-restful-api-in-cakephp) which I don't want to do.

How can I capture this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some "fun" with the map as well and gave up on it and did this:

```
$routes->connect('/:model/:foreignKey/:commentId', [
    'plugin' => 'Burzum/Comments',
    'controller' => 'Comments',
    'action' => 'edit',
    '_method' => 'PUT'
], [
    'pass' => [
        'model',
        'foreignKey',
        'commentId'
    ],
    '_ext' => null,
    'model' => $allowedModels,
    'commentId' => $idRegex,
    'foreignKey' => $idRegex,
]);
```

Let me know if the concept is clear for your or not. If not I'll change it to your actual case.

Comment: It does seem as though you gotta do this yourself via a super hared and complicate way :\ thanks, I will try it in the morning

Comment: I agree, but trying to get it done via the map turned out to be a time sink so I did it this way. More to write but it worked without wasting more time.